# What does # mean before echo?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using version 16.04 of Ubuntu

```
# echo command > filename
```

While I was following the package installation instructions, I found a sentence with # in front of echo

What does # mean before echo?

Sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: Everything from a `#`sign to the end of the line is a comment. Note: if your are learning bash `man bash` is your friend.

Comment: In the installation instructions, ```root@esm:~## echo "debfil....```
I was confused by the command, but now I know it was just a typo. Thank you.

Comment: It is a comment.  Not a typo.  A typo is accidental.  Comments are deliberate.

Comment: If you are learning bash, another good (well, reasonable and better than most) walk-through to give you practical learning of a good swath of bash is the [GNU Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). It's rather dated and not "perfect", but it covers a good majority of bash at an introductory level. Well worth spending a few hours working through the chapters and examples. Then you can go on to `man bash` or more narrowly tailored and less dated tutorials about any topic in bash where you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

In a script, `#` introduces a comment, i.e. the rest of the line is ignored.

In command line examples, `#` might represent the prompt (some shells use `#` for the root prompt and `$` for a normal user prompt).

Comment: In the installation instructions, ```root@esm:~## echo "debfil....```
I was confused by the command, but now I know it was just a typo. Thank you.